# SQL Script to find Foreign keys to a specific table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, constraints

Is there a query that will get me foreign keys directed at a specific table column? For example, say I had these three tables:

```
__________
|Table A |
----------
|Id      |
----------

___________
|Table B  |
-----------
|Id       |
|TableAId | (Foreign Key to TableA.Id)
-----------

___________
|Table C  |
-----------
|Id       |
|TableAId | (Foreign Key to TableA.Id)
-----------
```

I need a query along the lines of "Select * Foreign Keys directed at TableA.Id" that returned "Table C: TableAId", "Table B: TableAId". I'm browsing through some of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA system views, and it seems like I can easily see what foreign keys belong to Table A, or Table B individually, but I can't find where it says "Table C has a foreign key to Table A" specifically. I can figure out the specifics of the query, I just can't find the views I'm looking for (or I'm glossing over them). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Courtesy of Pinal Dave:](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/04/sql-server-2005-find-tables-with-foreign-key-constraint-in-database/)

```
SELECT 
    f.name AS ForeignKey,
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,
    fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
    OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,
    fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys AS f
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
```

Comment: Dude - this is awesome!  I was looking for a "join generator" but this is the manual sql for it.  I couldn't find an online tool for this (with SQL Server) - maybe I'll write my own!

Answer (score 0):

Added dynamic drop and create on dbo scheme.

```
DECLARE @l varchar(1) = char(13);
DECLARE @referenced_object_id varchar(MAX) = 'Replace_With_PK_Table_Name';

SELECT 
    fk.name AS ForeignKey,
    OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
    COL_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id,
    fkc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
    OBJECT_NAME (fk.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
    COL_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id,
    fkc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName,
    'ALTER TABLE [dbo].['+OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id)+'] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+fk.name+'];' DropFK,
    'ALTER TABLE [dbo].['+OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id)+']  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT ['+fk.name+'] FOREIGN KEY(['+COL_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id,
    fkc.referenced_column_id)+'])'+ @l +
    ' REFERENCES [dbo].['+OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id)+'] (['+COL_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id,
    fkc.referenced_column_id)+'])'+ @l +
    ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'+ @l +
    ' ON DELETE CASCADE;'+ @l +
    'ALTER TABLE [dbo].['+OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id)+'] CHECK CONSTRAINT ['+fk.name+'];' CreateFK
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys AS fk
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc ON fk.OBJECT_ID = fkc.constraint_object_id
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id)=@referenced_object_id
```

Comment: Since the reviewers rejected my edits directly on this answer, I'll provide the correction in here. At some point it should have been "...WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT ['+fk.name+'] FOREIGN KEY(['+COL_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id,fkc.parent_column_id)+'])'+ @l ..."

Comment: I do not think you should use parent_xxx instead of referenced_xxx for the FOREIGN KEY creation yet you can do that if you want to reverse the one to many keys it will probably not work as expected yet you are welcome to check it out.