# How do I check if the foreign key exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I want to find a foreign key in a table, but there are changes to rename/alter the primary key.  How can I determine the foreign key and primary key in the table?

Relevant code:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
         WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_Name'
```

Comment: Check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853187/sql-script-to-find-foreign-keys-to-a-specific-table

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this script at will, it returns a list with following values:

```
FKName  ParentTable  ParentColumnName    ReferencedTable    ReferencedColumnName
```

Script:

```
SELECT fk.Name AS 'FKName'
          ,OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) 'ParentTable'
          ,cpa.name 'ParentColumnName'
          ,OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) 'ReferencedTable'
          ,cref.name 'ReferencedColumnName'
    FROM   sys.foreign_keys fk
           INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                ON  fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
           INNER JOIN sys.columns cpa
                ON  fkc.parent_object_id = cpa.object_id
                AND fkc.parent_column_id = cpa.column_id
           INNER JOIN sys.columns cref
                ON  fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id
                AND fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id
```

Answer (score 3):

This query should give you a start - it gives you the foreign key names and the parent and reference table names and columns:

```
select
    OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id),
    OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id),
    scp.name,
    OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id),
    scr.name,
    fkc.constraint_column_id
from
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        inner join
    sys.columns scp
        on
            fkc.parent_object_id = scp.object_id and
            fkc.parent_column_id = scp.column_id
        inner join
    sys.columns scr
        on
            fkc.referenced_object_id = scr.object_id and
            fkc.referenced_column_id = scr.column_id
```

If you're just dealing with a single column foreign key, then you'll want to find a single row from this result set using an appropriate `WHERE` clause.

If you have a multi-column foreign key, then you'll need to consider matches across multiple rows and apply `GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id)` and use a `HAVING COUNT(*) =` *number of columns*.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to do it via information_schema:

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT rc.*
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS rc 

    LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU1 
        ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  
        AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 

    WHERE KCU1.TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' 
    AND rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'YOUR_FK_NAME' 
    -- AND rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'dbo' -- Optional
)
     PRINT 'I exist'
```