# SQL Server - A query to generate a JOINs path from one table to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-tables, join

If I know I need to JOIN Table 4 onto Table 1, but they have no columns in common, it takes some effort to find a Table 2 that has Column A in common with Table 1, then a Table 3 that has Column B in common with both Table 2 and Table 4, and so on, to eventually be able to pull that Table 4 into the query.

It sometimes requires joining a handful of unnecessary tables to get two joined that need joined. Maybe that's a necessary evil with some table setups, but how would you query so that SQL would create that path for you to save the trouble of figuring it out?

***Edit:***
What about this? (Thanks to [AHiggins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225845/ahiggins) for getting me on this track)

```
    SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN B.COLUMN_NAME = C.COLUMN_NAME 
        THEN D.COLUMN_NAME + ' is on both ' + A.TABLE_NAME + ' and ' + D.TABLE_NAME 
        ELSE 'ZZZNULLZZZ' 
        END AS 'QuickJoin',
    A.TABLE_NAME AS 'Starting Table', 
    B.COLUMN_NAME AS 'Column 1',
    B.TABLE_NAME AS 'Linking Table',
    C.COLUMN_NAME AS 'Column 2',
    D.TABLE_NAME AS 'Destination Table'


FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A 
    JOIN 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B ON 
            A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME AND
            A.TABLE_NAME <> B.TABLE_NAME        
    JOIN 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON 
            B.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME AND
            A.TABLE_NAME <> C.TABLE_NAME
    JOIN 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS D ON 
            C.COLUMN_NAME = D.COLUMN_NAME AND
            D.TABLE_NAME NOT IN (A.TABLE_NAME, B.TABLE_NAME, C.TABLE_NAME)

WHERE 
-- Starting Table
    A.TABLE_NAME = 'Starting Table'                 
-- Possible Column 1
    -- AND B.COLUMN_NAME = 'siteid'             
-- Possible Linking Table
    -- AND B.TABLE_NAME = 'possibleLinkingTable'
-- Possible Column 2
    -- AND C.COLUMN_NAME = 'possibleColumn2'    
-- Destination Table
    AND D.TABLE_NAME = 'Destination Table'                  


ORDER BY 
QuickJoin, B.COLUMN_NAME, B.TABLE_NAME, C.COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: You could create a view? There really isn't a way to have sql server automagically determine how to build your join across a number of tables.

Comment: *requires joining a handful of unnecessary tables*, well they are clearly necessary if you need them to join the other tables.

Comment: If there was a method to do this automatically, I'd be out of a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an automatic solution to this - however, there are things you might try that will help point you in the right direction.

One way, if your database is set up well, might be to look at [what foreign keys are set up in the database.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853223/1225845)

Another tool that might help would be checking to see what other tables have columns in common with either your source or destination.

```
SELECT A.TABLE_NAME, A.COLUMN_NAME, B.TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A 
     INNER JOIN 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B ON 
        A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME AND
        A.TABLE_NAME <> B.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = 'YourStartingTable' OR B.TABLE_NAME = 'YourDestinationTable'
```

Ultimately, you'll still need to go through the results yourself - but these two queries might help speed the time spent looking around.

Comment: Thanks, I adapted that and made a query that may help (with some manual effort still) to find a linking table between two tables with no key between them. I added the query to my original post. What do you think?